# React Router V4, Using render props with high order component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using **react router V4**, when i declare a Route i want wrap my component inside a High Order component, if I use HOC in

```
export default hoc(Component)
```

Then I put the component in the render prop, it works.
When I do this

```
`<Route exact path="/projects" render={(props) => (withNavHOC(<ProjectsContainer {...props}/>))} />`
```

It returns this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Route.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

Why it's happening? My Hoc works fine, it returns a valid react component:

`

```
const withNavHOC = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return class extends React.Component{
      render(){
          if(this.props.match.params.id){
              console.log("Here");
              return(
                  <div>
                      <ProjectMenu/>
                      <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>
                  </div>)
          }
          return(
                  <div>
                      <Navigation/>
                      <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>
                  </div>
              )
          }
      }
};`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To HOC which is of course a simple function, we must pass "Component", not `<Component/>`.